# "sudo su -" vs. "sudo -i" and /etc/environment

Tags: sudo, su

On an Ubuntu 14.04 host that I frequently update (`apt-get update` followed by `apt-get full-upgrade`) I have an `/etc/environment` file with some critical variables in it.

Until recently `sudo -i -u fred env` would show that in `fred`'s login environment the environment variable `FOO` was set to the value from `/etc/environment`.

In the last few days (perhaps due to an update; I wasn't paying much attention) `sudo -l -u fred env` no longer has the variables from `/etc/environment`. However, `sudo su - fred -c env` shows that `su -` does get those variables set.

What's going on here? Ought not `sudo -i` be exactly like `sudo su -` but perhaps more reliable due to not including an extra program in the mix?

#### PAM Configuration

The contents of all the various `/etc/pam.d/` files appear to be ostensibly unchanged from what came with the distibution, but it's hard to be totally sure of this, especially on the 16.04 host where I have no access to the etckeeper logs. Below I include information from the Ubuntu 14.04 host demonstrating the problem and Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 hosts not demonstrating the problem. Comments have been removed from all examples below.

`/etc/pam.d/sudo` is the same on all hosts:

```
#%PAM-1.0

auth       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
auth       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-auth` is slightly different between the hosts. The 14.04/18.04 versions are below; the 16.04 host is missing the final `pam_cap.so` line:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
auth    required            pam_permit.so
auth    optional            pam_cap.so
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-account` is the same on all hosts:

```
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]    pam_unix.so 
account requisite           pam_deny.so
account required            pam_permit.so
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive` is the same on all hosts:

```
session [default=1]         pam_permit.so
session requisite           pam_deny.so
session required            pam_permit.so
session optional            pam_umask.so
session required    pam_unix.so
```

Comment: I can confirm that on a fresh install `/etc/environment` is set. I would double check everything and file a bug via `ubuntu-bug`.

Comment: Can you please include the contents of `/etc/pam.d/sudo` in your question?

Comment: @steeldriver Sure. I've included also the three config files that `pam.d/sudo` includes and a comparison across the non-working and two working systems (albeit different versions of Ubuntu).